# Neo4j How to get equal subset of data for all relationship types from a graph?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I use below query to get all node ID's and their corresponding relationship types, but I need only 100 records for each relationship types, I used LIMIT clause, but it didn't work.

```
MATCH (s)-[r]->(t)
WHERE type(r) IN ['LIVES_IN', 'FROM', 'STUDIES']
RETURN toString(id(s)) as source, toString(id(t)) AS target, type(r) as type
```

How can I get 100 records for each type of relationship using the cypher query, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the APOC function [apoc.agg.slice](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.agg/apoc.agg.slice/) to efficiently get just the first 100 results for each `type` (without having to get **all** the results for each `type` first):

```
MATCH (s)-[r]->(t)
WHERE TYPE(r) IN ['NEXT', 'BEGIN', 'END']
RETURN TYPE(r) AS type, apoc.agg.slice({source: TOSTRING(ID(s)), target: TOSTRING(ID(t))}, 0, 100) AS res
```

The abover query returns a row for each `type`, along with a list of 100 `source` and target `values`.

To get every result on a separate row:

```
MATCH (s)-[r]->(t)
WHERE TYPE(r) IN ['NEXT', 'BEGIN', 'END']
WITH TYPE(r) AS type, apoc.agg.slice({source: TOSTRING(ID(s)), target: TOSTRING(ID(t))}, 0, 100) AS res
UNWIND res AS row
RETURN type, row.source AS source, row.target AS target
```